# Uncertainty In ERA-Interim data

Tags: meteorology, climate-models, era

Greeting,
What is the estimated uncertainty value in Temperature, relative humidity, U and V winds of ERA-Interim data?

Comment: Do they make such estimations?

Answer (score 5):

There is no traceable uncertainty associated with each datum in the ERA-Interim reanalysis.

**However**, in ERA-5 there is an *ensemble*.  This multiplies the data volume, but it means you can use the spread between the ensemble members to get an estimate.  See [ERA-5 page](https://confluence.ecmwf.int//display/CKB/What+is+ERA5).  ECMWF want us to use ERA-5 now anyway.

Comment: That page doesn't exist anymore, but there's this: https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/CKB/ERA5%3A+uncertainty+estimation?searchId=HC1ESI8OY . There's a good paragraph there that describes the uncertainty that could be useful as a quote.